# regex matching url

Tags: php, regex, routes

In PHP, the klein routing will match as many routes as it can.
2 routes I have set up are conflicting.  They are:

```
$route1: '/websites/[i:websiteId]/users/[i:id]?'
```

and

```
$route2: '/websites/[i:websiteId]/users/[a:filename].[json|csv:extension]?'
```

This is the URL I'm trying to match, which I think should match the first and not the second, is:

```
/api/v1-test/websites/100/users/4
```

The regex produced for these two are:

```
$regex1: `^/api(?:/(v1|v1-test))/websites(?:/(?P<websiteId>[0-9]++))/users(?:/(?P<id>[0-9]++))?$`

$regex2: `^/api(?:/(v1|v1-test))/websites(?:/(?P<websiteId>[0-9]++))/users(?:/(?P<filename>[0-9A-Za-z]++))(?:\.(?P<extension>json|csv))?$`
```

I mean for it not to match if there is no '.csv'  or '.json'. The problem is that it is matching both routes.  For the second, the resulting filename is '4' and the extension is blank.

Sending /api/v1-test/websites/100/users/users.csv works correctly and only matches the second route.

I only have control over the route, not the regex or the matching.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bit here

```
(?:\.(?P<extension>json|csv))?
```

at the end of your second regex causes it to match whether or not there's a filename due to the `?` at the very end. Question marks mean `0 or 1 of the previous expression`. Get rid of that and, at the least, strings will only match this regex when they have the extension.

To make this change, just remove the question mark from your second route, like so:

```
$route2: '/websites/[i:websiteId]/users/[a:filename].[json|csv:extension]'
```

Comment: I didn't much like this answer when I first read it.  My naive understanding is that the ? says that anything after this is taken as parameters.

Comment: You're correct that the ? can be used to [label a subpattern](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php). But it happens that in PHP regex syntax (which the Klein routing system uses), the question mark has more than one use. The last ? in your route is being interpreted as the `0 or 1` [meta character](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php).

Comment: In fact, the last route example in the [Klein readme](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php#routing) has a very similar route to what you described, explicitly saying it results in an option file extension. If what you want is for route2 to require the extension, you should remove the trailing `?`.

Comment: Sorry, my keyboard locked up right after I wrote that and I didn't get to finish my thought.  Changing it to [json|csv:extension]+? fixes it. So you are right.

Comment: @BradWhite: does this work when the url looks like `/api/v1-test/websites/100/users/test`? (and do you want it to fork in this case?)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `match_type` is defined really... weirdly:

```
$match_types = array(
            'i' => '[0-9]++',
            'a' => '[0-9A-Za-z]++',
[...]
```

As such, you can't really capture a sequence corresponding to `[a-zA-Z]` only... The only option I see would be to use 3 routes:

```
$route1: '/websites/[i:websiteId]/users/[i:id]?'
$route2: '/websites/[i:websiteId]/users/[a:filename]'
$route3: '/websites/[i:websiteId]/users/[a:filename].[json|csv:extension]'
```

And to assign the same actions for routes 2 and 3. Then you would have this:

- `/api/v1-test/websites/100/users/` is matched by 1
- `/api/v1-test/websites/100/users/4` is matched by 1
- `/api/v1-test/websites/100/users/test` is matched by 2
- `/api/v1-test/websites/100/users/test.csv` is matched by 3

Which seems like the behavior you wanted.

Abother (easier) solution would be to take advantage of this bit of the documentation:

```
Routes automatically match the entire request URI.
If you need to match only a part of the request URI
or use a custom regular expression, use the @ operator.
```

You can then define your routes like this:

```
$route1: '@/websites/[0-9]+/users/[0-9]*$'
$route1: '@/websites/[0-9]+/users/[a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)?$'
```

Comment: Philosophically, I liked this answer better.  I thought that using multiple routes had potential. But I still need the ? because of all the parameters coming after.  So I'm not clear on how your change prevents user/4 from matching route 3.

Comment: So I'm wrong.  PHP understands the ? in the URL without me adding it to the route.

Comment: @BradWhite: well actually when I read my answer again, I think the first solution wouldn't work after all... user/4 wouldn't match route 3 cause it requires to have an extension after the filename. however user/4 would still match route 1 and 2, I think. However I'm pretty sure that the second solution is exactly what you're looking for.